Can't load data from DataTable inside SqLite table using DataAdapter and SQLiteCommandBuilder
I'm using Visual Studio Windows Form, c#, and i have a SqLite database with a working connection. I need to read a sheet from a Excel end store all columns and cells inside a table in my db.
In order to read data from Excel, I installed from NuGet packages ExcelDataReader and ExcelDataReader.DataSet.
Everything works fine until i try to load the DataTable inside the table db using adapter.Update(dt) In debug mode I see that dt is correctly populated and all rows and columns have been succesfully read by ExcelDataReader. By the way, when i call .Update(dt) method of SQLiteDataAdapter it throws no exception, but the table db is simply not updated.
Heres my code:
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

            SQLiteConnection Con = new SQLiteConnection(DataSource);
            Con .Open();
//read the .xlsx Excel
            FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
//change all columns name
            DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
            {
                ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                {
                    UseHeaderRow = true
                }
            });
           
//in debug mode I see dt correctly populated
            dt = result.Tables[0];

            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8 FROM TableDB", Con);

            SQLiteCommandBuilder SQLBuilder2 = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter2);
            SQLiteTransaction trans = GestoreSpuntisti2.BeginTransaction();
            adapter2.Update(dt);
            trans.Commit();

            Con.Close();


Excel columns datatype are the same in TabeleDB columns.
I use .Update method in many other instances and it always works fine, but now when I use it reading a Excel somethings goes wrong, but I don't know what.
Can you please help me? Thank you so much.

The solution of my problem is that when I try to Upload the DataTable dt I need to change the RowState property to .SetAdded():
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row.SetAdded();
        }

Thanks to #Ralf for the solution.
